# CollectionView and CompletionHandler

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, completionhandler

I am tryin to load my CollectionView after my data is loaded, but i dont know how exactly should i use a CompletionHandler to do it.
thank for help
my Code is bellow:
for getting data:

```
func GETData(){

    urlString = "https://api.backendless.com/v1/data/Pub?pageSize=10&offset="+String(offset)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)

    request.setValue(applicationId, forHTTPHeaderField: "application-id")
    request.setValue(secretKey, forHTTPHeaderField: "secret-key")

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data: NSData?,response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) in

        if let responseData = data
        {
            parseDATA(responseData)
        }

        })
    task.resume()

    offset+=(pubs.count-offset)
    urlString = "https://api.backendless.com/v1/data/Pub"
}
```

and for colelectionView load:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        pubs.removeAll()
        GETData()
        super.viewDidLoad()
        typealias  UIActivityViewControllerCompletionHandler = () -> Void

        print("AKTUAL: "+String(pubs.count))
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```

Comment: Once you parsed the data (`parseDATA()` as it seems), reload the UICollectionView.

Answer (score 0):

Reload the Collection View in the end of Success block of your Service Call like below

```
[collectionView reloadData];
```

You can also give reloadData Method in URLSession Delegates.

Comment: Hi, i am totally beginner of all of this Swift everything, could you please explain me how exactly do it. Thanks